# Read client data instead of server with ASPxGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, client-side, aspxgridview

I have the following code

```
objGrid.GetSelectedFieldValues("IsEnabled", function (values)
{
    if (values[0])
    {
        $('#btnEnable').hide();
        $('#btnDisable').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#btnEnable').show();
        $('#btnDisable').hide();
    }
}
```

This works fine but the grid performs a callback to the server for the data when the data is already in the client.

How can I get the grid to read the client data instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASPxClientGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) always use callback to fetch data. You can't avoid that.
There are two ways to fetch row data without ASP.NET callback:
1. Client side data caching explained in [this article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E123.aspx)
2. Use ajax queries. Get row key using [ASPxClientGridView.GetRowKey](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetRowKeytopic). Implement http handler that will receive row key and table/object name. Fetch data you need and send it back to browser. You can use jquery.ajax for this.